# Error Launching RoR app On Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to launch my first RoR app on Heroku, however it keeps crashing. I have moved the features directory to the root but it still crashes. Here are the new logs. Please help.

```
    2012-01-09T16:17:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-01-09T16:17:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<mai
n>'
2012-01-09T16:17:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-01-09T16:17:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-01-09T16:17:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-01-09T16:17:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2012-01-09T16:17:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p
36358 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   ****************************************
************************************************************
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **   Blueprint CSS Compressor
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **     - Column Count: 24
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **   Builds compressed files from the so
urce directory.
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **     - Column Width: 30px
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **     - Gutter Width: 10px
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **   Output to: /app/app/assets/styleshe
ets/lib/blueprint/../../blueprint
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   ****************************************
************************************************************
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **     - Total Width : 950px
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     Assembling to default blueprint path
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:       + src/reset.css
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **   Grid Settings:
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:       + src/typography.css
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   **
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:       + src/forms.css
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:       + src/grid.css
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/blu
eprint/core_ext.rb:37:in `open'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/blu
eprint/core_ext.rb:37:in `string_to_file'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/blueprint/
core_ext.rb:37:in `initialize': Permission denied - /app/app/assets/stylesheets/
lib/blueprint/../../blueprint/screen.css (Errno::EACCES)
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/blu
eprint/compressor.rb:140:in `block in generate_css_files'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/blu
eprint/compressor.rb:109:in `each'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/blu
eprint/compressor.rb:109:in `generate_css_files'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/blu
eprint/compressor.rb:42:in `generate!'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `depend_on'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency
'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/a
ctivesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/com
press.rb:167:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher
>'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<t
op (required)>'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ailties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in
 <main>'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `
block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_requi
re>:29:in `require'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `new'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `map'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `
block (2 levels) in <main>'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `
eval'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
block in <main>'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
new'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r
ack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `n
ew'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<
main>'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/
gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<mai
n>'
2012-01-09T16:17:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load
'
2012-01-09T16:18:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-01-09T16:18:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2012-01-09T16:18:29+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET freezin
g-journey-6798.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-09T16:18:29+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET freezin
g-journey-6798.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 byt
es=
2012-01-09T16:18:29+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 192.68.112.171 - - [09/Jan/2012:08:18:2
9 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/
535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7" freezing-journey-6798
.heroku.com
2012-01-09T16:18:29+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 192.68.112.171 - - [09/Jan/2012:08:18:2
9 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) A
ppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7" freezing-j
ourney-6798.heroku.com
2012-01-09T16:18:33+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET freezin
g-journey-6798.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-09T16:18:33+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 192.68.112.171 - - [09/Jan/2012:08:18:3
3 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/
535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7" freezing-journey-6798
.heroku.com
2012-01-09T16:18:33+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 192.68.112.171 - - [09/Jan/2012:08:18:3
3 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) A
ppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7" freezing-j
ourney-6798.heroku.com
2012-01-09T16:18:36+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET freezin
g-journey-6798.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-01-09T16:18:36+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 192.68.112.171 - - [09/Jan/2012:08:18:3
6 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/
535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7" freezing-journey-6798
.heroku.com
2012-01-09T16:18:36+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET freezin
g-journey-6798.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 byt
es=
2012-01-09T16:18:36+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 192.68.112.171 - - [09/Jan/2012:08:18:3
6 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) A
ppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7" freezing-j
ourney-6798.heroku.com
2012-01-09T16:18:38+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 192.68.112.171 - - [09/Jan/2012:08:18:3
8 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/
535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7" freezing-journey-6798
.heroku.com
2012-01-09T16:18:39+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET freezin
g-journey-6798.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 byt
es=
2012-01-09T16:18:39+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 192.68.112.171 - - [09/Jan/2012:08:18:3
9 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) A
ppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7" freezing-j
ourney-6798.heroku.com
```

SO here are the logs please help

Answer (score 1):

You have a directory in the wrong place:

```
features / step_definitions / blueprint_steps.rb
```

should stay in Rails root, not in app/stylesheets

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have moved the features directory to the rails root. However it still crashes. Here are the new logs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to generate file from your app:

```
from /app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/blueprint/core_ext.rb:37:in `string_to_file'
/app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/blueprint/core_ext.rb:37:in `initialize': Permission denied - /app/app/assets/stylesheets/lib/blueprint/../../blueprint/screen.css (Errno::EACCES)
```

Heroku is readonly, you cannot write file in the app folder.